# How to add a hyphen in a TextBox input in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET textbox where I want to add a hyphen in the textbox input if the length of the input is > 5. For example, if I type 123456789, the entry should show like this: 12345-6789

How to do this?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.phone').on('input', function() {
  this.value.length < 5 || this.value.charAt(5) == '-' || 
    $(this).val( [this.value.slice(0,5), '-', this.value.slice(5)].join('') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="phone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var value = $("#your-textbox-id-here").val();

  if (value.length >= 5) {
      value = value.substring(0, 5) + "-" + value.substring(5);
      //console.log(value);
  }
```

Comment: You could probably achieve better results using javascript mask formatting libraries. Google for that.

Comment: can you suggest me more details, what event i can use for example onkeypress or something

Comment: if you are working with jquery, you can attach the code above to $("#your-textbox-id-here").change(function() { ... });