# Asp.net Textbox dynamic adding dash -

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i have 1 TextBox is Asp.net this textbox is Zip-Code / Postal code like "41-200"
How i can dynamic(when user writes this) add dash "-" after 2 character.

I try used update panel but doesnt work

Comment: Hi! Can you add some code as an example of your problem?

Comment: There's a `jQuery` solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28048847/3793448) which might be of some use to you